# How to make a scene run in background unity2d

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity2D project and I have bit of confusion.

Let us consider there are two, scene1 and scene2 and I am using `SceneManager.LoadScene` to load the level. I am using C# to code.

So When I switch form scence1 to scene2 will the scene1 will be destroyed?? or it will be in pause state? What will be the condition of Scence1.

Comment: it's worth noting that in ordinary projects "loading a scene" is no big deal.  yes, you just use `LoadScene` to "swap back and fore between scenes". it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

[Application.LoadLevel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html) is deprecated

You should use [SceneManager.LoadScene](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

Now when you load Scene2, Scene1 will be destroyed depending on the  [SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html) parameter given to SceneManager.LoadScene.

Also, even if you choose to delete the scene, every GameObject you called [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) for won't be destroyed:

```
void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

Now as far as I know, there is no way to pause a particular scene when many are loaded. You'd have to implement this in your code. Maybe by using [SceneManager.GetActiveScene](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html)

Feel free to improve this answer!